Eating cookies from the plate game: If your opponent is the one left with no valid moves, you win.

There are $20$ cookies on a plate. $A$ and $B$ play a game where on each turn, the player can eat as many cookies as he likes, as long as he eats at least one cookie but at most half of the cookies that are on the plate at the time of his turn. Whoever cannot make a valid move on his turn loses the game. $B$ lets $A$ choose to go first or second. Should A choose to go first or second to win the game?

I know I didn't really provide any of my thoughts / what I tried on this, but that's because I'm not very sure how to approach this problem. To me, it seems that choosing to go first or second does not decide whether $A$ wins or loses the game. (However, I cannot prove that, either.)

If there is only one cookie left on the plate, then it is impossible to eat at least one cookie and at most half of the cookies on the plate.

@5xum Yup, and so whoever's turn it is would lose.

Every number of cookies is either a first-player win or a second-player win.  1 cookie is a second-player win.  2 cookies is a first-player win, as eating 1 cookie leads to a second-player win.  Etc…. what type of position is 20 cookies?

@K.Jiang No, my point is that if there is one cookie on the plate, then according to the rules, I need to eat at least one cookie, and also I need to eat at most $\frac12$ cookies, so the number of cookies $c$ must satisfy $c\geq 1\land c\leq\frac12$, and such a number does not exist.

You can state unequivocally that it does matter whether A goes first or not.

@5xum The rules don't say that you need to eat any cookies at all - if no such $c$ exists, then the player just loses. Am I misunderstanding?

The key is to assume that each player plays perfectly rationally, forcing the other player to a losing position whenever possible, and otherwise delaying loss as long as possible

@K.Jiang No, the rules state that the player loses when there are no cookies left. If the player is allowed to simply eat $0$ cookies, then if there is only one cookie left, the game is a draw. Each player in turn decides to eat $0$ cookies ad infinitum.

@5xum Where do the rules say the player loses when there are no cookies left?

@K.Jiang In the title of the post...

@5xum Oh, I did not even notice the title. I was just going off of the description in the question itself. I agree, the title seems wrong and contradicts the description in the body of the question.

As hinted at in the comments, you can approach problems like this by classifying the states of the game as winning or losing positions. There is only one number needed to describe the state of the game, which is the number of cookies left on the plate.
If there is only $1$ cookie, there is nothing that the current player can do - they lose the game. So we will label $1$ as a losing position. If there are $2$ cookies, the current player can force the other player into a losing position by eating $1$ cookie (which is indeed "at least $1$ and at most half" of $2$), which leaves $1$ (a losing position for the other player). So this is a winning position.
If there are $3$ cookies, the current player is forced to eat $1$ cookie, so it is a losing position. If there are $4$ cookies, the player can eat $1$ to force the next player to $3$, so $4$ is winning. If there are $5$ cookies, eating $2$ cookies forces the player to $3$, so $5$ is also winning. The same argument applies to $6$ cookies (eat $3$).
$7$ cookies is losing because all the possibilities go to $4$, $5$, or $6$, which are winning. Anything between $8$ and $14$ (inclusive) is winning because you can go to $7$ (which is losing).
$15$ cookies is losing because all moves lead to winning positions. Then, $16$ through $20$ are all winning.
So, you want to go first to win the game. You probably noticed a pattern in the above, which is that any state of the form $2^n - 1$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is losing, and all others are winning. You can try to prove this conjecture.
